# Using spreadsheet functions, can we create a new row by copying format properties of another row in the same sheet?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml

Using spreadsheet functions, can we create a new row by copying format properties of another row in the same sheet programtically?

In my excel template, I have some border styles and sum formula at the end of table, can I create a new row in last with that styles copied and summation formula applied?
For example in my template I have some tabular data starting from row 10-15 with some format styles for that rows, can I copy that format and add new row below it?

Comment: Looking at the docs, there doesn't seem to be a built-in CF Spreadsheet function to accomplish this.  With that said, I'd suggest doing a search on an Apache POI solution.  Here's a link that will provide you with a good start.  Of course, you'll have to translate from Java to ColdFusion, but this looks promising. http://www.zachhunter.com/2010/05/npoi-copy-row-helper/

Comment: @user12031119 - NPOI is actually the C# version of that library, but the syntax is very similar.

Comment: AFAIK, it isn't supported in CF2018 either.  Later versions of POI have support for this feature. It won't help for CF10 (eol'd) but you might submit an [enhancement request](https://tracker.adobe.com) for newer versions.

Comment: Use the function `spreadsheetFormatCell (spreadsheetObj, formatData, rowNumber, columnNumber);` to format the data cell at a given (rowNumber,columnNumber) in the spreadsheet. _FormatData_ is a struct containing the format information. See [documentation on spreadsheetformatcell function](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-s/spreadsheetformatcell.html). Say, your spreadsheet has 20 columns, for example. To format row 16, you could apply `spreadsheetFormatCell (spreadsheetObj, formatData, 16, columnNumber);`, the columnNumber ranging from 1 to 20.